# Como hago volver las paletas?

Tags: java, netbeans, interfaz-gráfica

Mientra hacia ejercicios de interfaz gráfica en mi netbeans yo de forma erroronea e inconsciente borré las paletas que aparesen en la parte lateral derecha de la pantalla y ahora no se como sacar las herramientas para crear las interfaces. Necesito ayuda, ¿como hago volver las paletas?.

Answer (score 2):

Ir al menú:

Window -> IDE Tools -> Palette

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Uff gracias. Me sirvió de gran ayuda.